# How can I show id values into table from three different sql tabless

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I have state (table name sehirler) and regions (table bolgeler) which links together. When I try to register a new client, it sends only values. For ex; 66 state, 5 region. How can I insert both state id and name in one column named sehiradii table for client database.

I tried to get new queries like 6 and 1 as "6.Ankara" and "1.Cankaya" into new table. But i didnt find any solution.
sehirler (tableanme) (id, sehiradi) /// musteriler (tablename) (sehiradii, bolgeadi)/// bolgeler(tablename) (id, bolgeadi, sehirid(foreign key of sehirler))

```
<td>Şehir</td>
<td> <select id="sehirid" name="sehiradii"  onchange="sehir_sec()">
<option>Şehir Seçiniz</option>
<?php
$res= mysqli_query($link,"select * from sehirler");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
?>
<option name="sehiradii" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['sehiradi']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</td>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Müşteriyi Kaydet" class="mkayit-butonu">
```

I used funtion to call bolgeler from sehirler.

```
function sehir_sec()
{
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php? 
sehir="+document.getElementById("sehirid").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("bolgeid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Ajax.php used for bolgeler

```
<?php
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link, "register");
$sehir=$_GET["sehir"];   ajax.php
if ($sehir!=""){
$res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from bolgeler where sehirid=$sehir");
echo "<select>";
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<option>"; echo $row["bolgeadi"];echo"</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

I expect that can it be seen like 66 and 5 as "6.Ankara" and "1.Cankaya" into table, or how can I insert values in one column like 6.Ankara

Comment: What I want is that Person, state_name, region name. But it gives me Person, state_id, region_id

Comment: You need to join those 3 tables and select the columns you want.

Comment: Something like this: `Select person.person_name, state.name, region.name from person left join state on person.state_id = state.state_id left join region on person.region_id = region.region_id where person.person_id = id`

Comment: [link](https://prntscr.com/oc4mai) in here you will see dashboard.php's table. It show only state and region id.  here its code [link](https://prntscr.com/oc4kml). So, how can insert code like ur said. and where? I upload screenshots on Lightshot.